# Pattern for unvalidated data, validated data and validation

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns

In my Ktor REST API, I receive JSON. This is conveniently deserialised for me into simple data classes by `kotlinx.serialization`. Before I can proceed using this data I have to apply some validation. Then I can pass it on to to other parts of the code.

I would like a clear separation between deserialised but unvalidated data, the validation itself, and validated code.

For example, I have something to the effect of:

```
@Serializable
data class Input(val something: Int)

fun Input.validate() {
    if(something < 5) { throw WhateverException("invalid") }
}
```

But there's a few issues with this: When receiving an instance of `Input` anywhere, I can't be sure it's been validated already, so to be safe I'll call `validate()` again.

So, to avoid this I would like for `validate()` to return some version of `Input` that tells me the data is valid, and so that I can have method signatures in my codebase that accept validated data only.

I know I can copy the class `Input` to a private one called `ValidatedInput` and have `validate()` return that, but that looks like code duplication. (I will end up having dozens of classes like `Input`.) Also that will prevent be from having an interface specifying `Input` to have the `validate` method and have it return something like `Validated<Input>`

How do I design my classes and methods to clearly express this separation, and without repeating code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that `Input` is validated, you have to somehow put it in the type system. Since `Validated<Input>` is a no-go for you (I would prefer doing it this way), maybe you could turn it around by giving `Input` some kind of validation token as a type parameter?

For example like this:

```
data class Input<out Validation>(val something: Int)

sealed class Validation
object Validated : Validation()
object NotValidated : Validation()

fun Input<NotValidated>.validate(): Input<Validated> {
    return if(something < 5) { throw RuntimeException("invalid") }
    else Input<Validated>(something)
}
```

Doing it the other way (`Validated<Input>`) is a bit more flexible in my opinion. It also doesn't mix any code about validation into the `Input` class (like the validation token would). So, for example, you could do something like this:

```
sealed class Validated<T>
class Valid<T>(val value: T) : Validated<T>()
class Invalid<T>(val error: Exception): Validated<T>()

fun Input.validate(): Validated<Input> {
    return if(something < 5) Invalid(RuntimeException("invalid"))
    else Valid(this)
}

fun performAction(input: Valid<Input>) { 
    TODO("Do something with the valid Input")
}

fun main() {
    val validated = Input(5).validate()

    val result = when(validated) {
        is Valid -> performAction(validated)
        is Invalid -> throw validated.error
    }

    println(result)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It didn't occur to me to turn it around, and your use of `out` made me learn about covariant/contravariant generic arguments. I'm not opposed to something like `Validated<Validatable>`, I just didn't know how to implement it this way while preserving a nice API. (My question description probably wasn't very clear.) Could you please explain in more detail what your preferred solution is?

Comment: @Patrick I updated the answer with an example using `Validated<Input>`.

Comment: Note that actually enforcing this in a code base of some size would require you to write either `Input<Validated>` or `Valid<Input>` on every function that takes an `Input` as a parameter though. That can get quite cumbersome. So usually I just validate the input at the edge of the program, then just assume that all values are already validated everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can move validation to `Input` initialization:

```
@Serializable
data class Input(val something: Int) {
    init {
        validate()
    }
}
```

If you do it all `Input` instances will be valid.

Comment: I would like separation between serialisation, validation and validated data. This solution doesn't provide that.